# "db.createUser is not a function" and "password can't be empty"

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to setup the authentication on MongoDB. I've uncommented `auth=true` in configuration file and restarted the server. The first connection via **mongo** was rejected. The second one (immediately after the first one) went through and I got this in the logs:

```
Sat Apr 12 14:56:46 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:44001 #1
Sat Apr 12 14:56:46 [conn1] note: no users configured in admin.system.users, allowing localhost access
```

While in console, I am able to execute commands, however if I try to follow any of the numberous tutorials (including the official ones), I get either `db.createUser is not a function` when executing `db.createUser()` or `password can't be empty` when executing `db.addUser()`:

[image: Mongo output]

The object which I am passing is:

```
{
    user: "username",
    pwd: "passphrase",
    roles: [ 
        { 
            role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", 
            db: "admin" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

What version of mongodb are you running? db.createUser was introduced in version 2.6

> > Deprecated since version 2.6: Use db.createUser() and db.updateUser() instead of db.addUser() to add users 
> >     to MongoDB.
> >
> > In 2.6, MongoDB introduced a new model for user credentials and privileges, as described in Security Introduction. To use db.addUser() on MongoDB 2.4, see db.addUser() in the version 2.4 of the MongoDB Manual.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/

Comment: If you are using RoboMongo, you will still get an error, even if using 2.6.x. See:  https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/542

Comment: Looks like that's deprecated, use this now: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/

Answer (score 3):

Regarding my experience, this issue also happens when you have an old version of Mongo Shell.

So, be sure to have the Mongo Shell according to the version of your MongoDB Server.

> $ mongo
>
> MongoDB shell version **v3.4.10**
>
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>
> MongoDB server version: **3.4.10**

Below:

---

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-01-16T11:43:00.195-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2018-01-16T11:43:00.195-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-01-16T11:43:00.195-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-01-16T11:43:00.687-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>
> use admin
switched to db admin
>  
> db.createUser( {user:"mongoloide", pwd:"mongoloide*2017", roles:["root"]} )
Successfully added user: { "user" : "mongoloide", "roles" : [ "root" ] }
```